# External library in Metro UI

Tags: .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to add external library dll to my Metro style app in visual studio 11 in windows 8 and i got the error 
**"A reference to '...' could not be added. The project targets '.NETCore' while the file reference targets '.NETFramework'. This is not a supported scenario. "**

Is there any way I can add library ?   library is in .net 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Metro supports only to add libraries written for Metro. You can create a class library in visual studio, so called windows metro style class library. Importing native .Net dlls is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an external WPF library which I intend to refer to in the metro apps. Isn't there a way to refer to .Net 4.0 dlls in metro projects?

Comment: I am looking for the same thing